# wp7, listbox of ~80 items not populating when navigating back to it

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, listbox, windows-phone-7.1

I think this has a lot to do with how I'm structuring my listbox in XAML and the data virtualization happening with the box itself, but I need some help being pointed in the correct direction.

I currently have a pivot page with a listbox in the first page. When a user navigates to this pivot page with the listbox, the listbox is created in xaml by the following code:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="objects">

       <ListBoxItem x:Name="item1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock/>
                <TextBlock/>
            </StackPanel>
       </ListBoxItem>

       <ListBoxItem x:Name="item2">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock/>
                <TextBlock/>
            </StackPanel>
       </ListBoxItem>

       //So forth to ListBoxItem item80

       <ListBoxItem x:Name="item80">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock/>
                <TextBlock/>
            </StackPanel>
       </ListBoxItem>

  </ListBox>
```

It takes about 2 seconds to navigate to this page with the 80 listbox items, and I can imagine that it's because it's rendering this information. That is a different problem, and again I believe it is because of the XAML coding.

When I click on a listboxitem, it goes to a new page of mine. However, my problem is that when I scroll to, say, item80 and click on it, and then navigate back to the pivot/listbox page, the items are not visible until I scroll all the way back up, and then scroll back down again.

Is there a way to get around this? They're static listbox items and nothing is being added or deleted from the list. All resources (such as any pictures) are in the phone by default and there is nothing external (web calls, etc) happening to gather resources. Any suggestions are helpful with this.

Comment: You'd be much better off using moving the items into an array of objects and then using a `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to specify the XAML used to display them. Not sure if it's tied to your performance issue, but your usage is uncommon.